# Need help for Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table x which is returning 20 rows and table x have 6 columns 
and now  I have one more table y which have only one column with 5 rows
 now  i would like to return all rows and all columns of x plus single column rows of table y and all these 5 values of y should be repeated 4 times because table x have 20 rows.  And if table x have 18 rows then In last iteration of table y only 3 values should be repeated .

Example :
Table x:

```
Id name
1  peter
2  john
3  robin
4  amy
5  joseph
6  king
7  brain
8  nancy
```

Now table y:

```
Rank
X
Y
Z
```

Final output I want,

```
Id name        rank
1  peter       X
2  john        Y
3  robin       Z
4  amy         X
5  joseph      Y
6  king        Z
7  brain       X
8  nancy       Y
```

I will appreciate for your help ,

Thanks and regards, 
Vijay dubey

Comment: Just for the record, I think this is a good question and don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and modular arithmetic:

```
select x.*, y.rank
from (select x.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from x
     ) x join
     (select y.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from y
     ) y
     on mod(x.seqnum, y.cnt) = mod(y.seqnum, y.cnt);
```

Comment: thanks a lot Gordon for such a brief and wonderful logic , lot of thanks :-)